# Webdriver exception selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid2

Not able to launch test after setting all , here is code :

```
public void browserSetup() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capability =DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeurl),capability);
        capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capability.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(PageUrlReff.HomePageUrl);
    }
```

Getting following error:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property

Answer (score 0):

On the machine that is running your Selenium node please download the binaries for

1. ChromeDriver
2. GeckoDriver
3. IEDriverServer (Assuming your node is a WINDOWS box, if not, then you don't need this)

and make the location of these binaries available as part of your PATH environment variable. After that your automation should run fine and you wouldn't be seeing this error message.